# relation or relationship between two things

Tags: word-choice

> He philosophized that the ghee and the leaf are related.

If I change this sentence, which one is suitable, relation or relationship.

> He philosophized about  the **relation** between the ghee and the leaf.
>
> He philosophized about the **relationship** between the ghee and the leaf.

Comment: This should help you http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15208/relation-versus-relationship

Comment: I don't see either of them as very good.  "Philosophised" doesn't normally take a direct object / isn't transitive, so your constructions sound odd.

Comment: You could say "he philosophised ABOUT the relationship/relation between....", and that would be okay (relation and relationship are synonyms in this context, and so are interchangeable)

Comment: See: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15208/relation-versus-relationship